# What does vbi represent in C++ under Microsoft compiler

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Sample code:

```
class A
{
protected:
    int a;
};

class B : public virtual A
{
protected:
    int b;
};

class C : public virtual A
{
protected:
    int c;
};

class D : public B, public C
{
protected:
    int d;
};
```

I use the **cl /d1 reportSingleClassLayout** command to see the object modle of **Class D**, then I find that there is a data named vbi which I have never seen.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be **virtual base information**. The table is basically telling you that the shared implementation of `A` (shared by `B` and `C`) is 20 bytes from the start of the class `D`.